# He wants to go to the movies. vs. He wants to go to the movie

Tags: grammar

1. He wants to go to the movies.
2. He wants to go to the movie.
   [Can we use #2?]
3. He wants to see the movies.
4. He wants to see the movie.
   [Both are okay, right?]
5. He wants to watch the movies.
6. He wants to watch the movie.
   [Are both okay? Can we use 'watch' insted of 'see'?]
7. He wants to watch movies.
8. He wants to watch a movie.
   [Are both okay?]

Comment: *movie* = a certain movie. OTOH, *(the) movies* = the cinema; place where movies are screened; movies in general; cinema in general.

Answer (score 1):

They are all perfectly good English, however there have different meanings.

**"He wants to go to the movies"** means he wants to visit a cinema but the actual film is not specified

**"He wants to go to the movie"** means he wants to visit a cinema to see (or watch, they mean the same thing in this context) a specific film which has been mentioned previously.

**"He wants to see the movie (or movies)"** usually means that he wants to see/watch a  (or a number of) previously specified film (or films) but might not mind where he sees them or what medium is used (he would probably be happy with DVD or streaming in his own home). However it *could* mean that he wants sight of the physical film reels or DVDs.

**"He wants to watch the movies"** means the same as "he wants to see the movies" except that it cannot normally be used to say that he wants to see the physical media (anyone who wanted to stare at physical media for a long time would have very unusual tastes).

**"He wants to watch a movie"** means that he wants to watch (or see) an unspecified film using an unspecified medium at an unspecified location. He might be happy visiting a cinema, seeing it on the TV at home, watching it on a DVD player in the back of a moving car or any one of number of other possibilities.

**"He wants to watch movies"** means that he wants to spend an extended period of time watching an unspecified number of unspecified movies in unspecified locations on unspecified media. It can also be used to refer to an habitual part of his life as in "What does he want to do in his free time?" "He wants to watch movies, we never talk or play board games and if we go out it's always to the cinema."

I think I've covered it all. "See" and "watch" have different meanings in general use but mean the same thing when talking about sitting through films, plays and television programmes.